# Get element after a specific sibling element by the sibling's text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="account-type">
   <h3>Assets</h3>
   <ul> ...lots of data in here... </ul>
<div class="account-type">
   <h3>Liabilities</h3>
   <ul> .... lots of elements in here... </ul>
```

How do I isolate the div tag with the class of "account-type" that is the direct parent of the h3 tag with the text "Liabilities"?  I need to isolate it and then loop through all of the elements in it's ul tags.

Comment: `$('h3:contains("Liabilities")').closest('.account-type')`

Comment: your html is invalid

Comment: Why not use a CSS selector. `querySelectorAll(.account-type > h3).map(x => x.parentElement`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox That would return the first one, not the second one.

Comment: It's just an html snipit, but it is valid html.  This is the exact structure I am working with.

Comment: @Taplar forgot to map

Comment: @evolutionxbox That would still return multiple.  They only want the one related to the Liabilities.

Comment: Really unclear.... so they click on an h3 and you want the UL after it? Or you want the parent of what was clicked?

Comment: @epascarello - I just need the direct parent of the h3 tag with the text 'liabilities'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `<ul>` should come after `<h3>`, you can use this combination:

1. [:contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)
2. [:next](https://api.jquery.com/next/#next-selector)
3. [children](https://api.jquery.com/children/#children-selector)

```js
function getItemByTitle( title ){
  return $(`h3:contains("${title}")`).next('ul').children()
}

var listItems = getItemByTitle("Liabilities")

console.log(listItems.length)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="account-type">
   <h3>Assets</h3>
   <ul></ul>
</div>
<div class="account-type">
   <h3>Liabilities</h3>
   <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Damn that was fast.  And slick.  Nice.

Answer (score 0):

There is no text match in DOM so need to select all the elements, look to see if the text matches. If it does select the parent.

```js
const h3 = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".account-type > h3")).find(elem => elem.textContent.trim() === 'Liabilities');
console.log(h3)
const div = h3.closest(".account-type");
console.log(div);
const lis = div.querySelectorAll("ul li");
console.log(lis.length);

// or
console.log(h3.nextElementSibling.children)
```

```html
<div class="account-type">
  <h3>Assets</h3>
  <ul></ul>
</div>
<div class="account-type">
  <h3>Liabilities</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```